# Is expressing a desire for harm the same as making a threat?

Tags: meaning

If someone says "I hope you and your family burn to death" and "I wish I could slit your throat", are these considered threats, or are they just someone expressing a hope (however repugnant)?

I would think for them to be threats, they would have to be reworded to be more like "I will burn you and your family to death" and "I will slit your throat". Is that not the case?

edit: I am asking if the above statements expressing a desire can strictly and/or technically be considered to be a threat, when looking at a definition from a reputable dictionary (merriam-webster or oxford, not dictionary.com).

I am not asking about how people might perceive them, as that has nothing to do with whether or not the statements are actually threats or not.

Editing because I can't reply to comments yet.

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning of the word *threat* in English? Or are you asking about how we interpret veiled threats? The latter isn't really on-topic here.

Comment: You may want to log in using your previous account. Your edits are now passed through the suggested edit queue.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to make a totally objective ruling on this, since it's totally based on how the sentence is interpreted. For example, think of the classic Mobster threat: "You've got a real nice shop; it'd be a real shame if something happened to it." How could you come up with a strict dictionary based rule that would define if that sentence is a threat?

Comment: I don't think you'd generally get arrested for saying those things, but I could see someone succeeding in getting an order of protection if you said those things about the person.

Answer (score 1):

According to [dictionary.com's page on 'threat'](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/threat):

> *"a declaration of an intention or determination to inflict punishment, injury, etc."*

*"I hope that ..."* is not really a threat (although it will frequently be interpreted as one).

However, *"I wish that I could ..."* is *determination to* and therefore is a threat by definition. It will also likely be interpreted as *"I will ... when I get the chance."*.